# deploying class Library in Visual studio online build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, continuous-integration

I am currently working on a personal project but I want to use Azure & Visual studio online build facilities for self teaching purpose. I am having a hard time resolving this problem :

I have a wpf app connected to an azure web api.
Wpf app is in its own Git repo, web api is also in its own Git repo.
Since both apps shared a common model, I put common model in its own repo as well to avoid code duplication.
I must be missing something ....

**What I want to do**
When I build on Visual studio online, I want to build "common" and feed its output dlls to webapi and wpf apps so that they can reference the model.

**Solutions considered so far**

1. nuget package

making a nuget package of "model" but where do I push it ? It's definitively not going to be of any value to nuget.org so no go.
I would need some private nuget repo in visual studio online, not sure it exists.

2. postbuild event

I also considered adding a post build event to the "common" build and copy its bin*.dll output to wpf and webapi apps to some "dependencies folder" but I find this dirty, Moreover I am not sure a build can push its output to the input of another build (I know Jenkins can but I am unsure about visual studio online), Moreover, how can I reference dlls which do not exist yet in my csprj ?

3. commit bins in repo (ugh)

Of course, I could build model locally and push the resulting dll in the git repos but, well, I am against putting binaries in versioning tools :)

4. Change my design
   Consider that WPF only needs dto and not the real entities (which is true) but webapi will need to deserialize dtos anyway so back to square one, but with dtos this time :)

Thanks for your input !

Comment: A Nuget package doesn't have to be on Nuget.org. You can put the package in a folder on the build server if you want. Also, Team services has a Package Management component which is basically your own private Nuget server but it is not free as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to CrowCoder ! 
That's exactly what I needed :  using the "Package Management" extension in visual studio online, which is free up to 5 users.
Steps required :

1. configure nuget on my local machine,
2. create the nuspec,
3. create the feed,
4. package the model library
5. configure the build to push the library to the feed
6. use nuget packages to reference model